# snowpack: reference files outside of project folder

Tags: snowpack

Our team develops a bunch of JavaScript browser apps. These apps share functionality (core) and Web Components (shared). The folder structure is:

```
/apps
     /app-1
     /app-2
     ...
/core
/shared
```

Each folder contains a `src` folder.

Considering using snowpack in the folder `app-1` I want to reference js files in `/core/src` or `/shared/src` both for development (using `snowpack dev`) and packaging (using `snowpack build`)

1. is this possible?
2. are there best practices how to achieve this?
3. are there examples for such a situation (or a similar one)

*What I tried:*

**Step 1:** I used paths like this: `../../core/src/router.js`. This didn't work, maybe because the resources were outside of the webroot of the test server (`snowpack dev`).

**Step 2:** I created two symlinks:

```
apps/app-1/src/@core   -> ../../../core/src
apps/app-1/src/@shared -> ../../../shared/src
```

Now the local server found all the resources. The build process however found only those files, that were direct children of `core/src` or `shared/src`, but not any file within a subfolder as e.g. `shared/src/component/filter.js`.

Any ideas or thoughts?

*Appendix*

The `snowpack.config.json` of app-1:

```json
{
    "devOptions": {
        "port": 8082,
        "open": "none"
    },
    "mount": {
        "public": "/",
        "src": "/_dist_"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@snowpack/plugin-babel",
        "@snowpack/plugin-dotenv",
        "@snowpack/plugin-sass"
    ]
}
```

Example for import in `app-1/src/handler`:

```js
import { loadRoute } from '../@core/router'    // works fine
import '../@shared/component/filter'           // does not work
// or:
import { loadRoute } from '../@core/router.js' // works fine, too
import '../@shared/component/filter.js'        // does not work neither
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem just adding:

```
  workspaceRoot: '..',
```

to your `snowpack.config.js` file.

Basically it tells snowpack to process everything from the parent folder (`..`) through it's pipeline. It will pick up dependencies and process everything.

In your case, you could import files from `shared` in `app-1` by using relative paths, and without creating any symlinks:

```
import something from '../shared/something';
```

You can find more about `workspaceRoot` property in [snowpack's documentation](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#workspaceroot).

Comment: This was useful for me also because I wanted to import `package.json` (in order to display the app's name/version for example) in the UI. As in: `import module from '../package.json'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify a relative path to the folder in your `mount` object as another key:

```js
{
  "mount": {
    "../../shared": "/_dist_"
  }
}
```

this should serve your files from the `shared` directory from the `/_dist_` folder.

Comment: I followed this way, and snow find js files in ../../shared/dist, but canont find ../../shared/node_modules nor dependencies in it.